# Get comment Permissions for Client Id in Instagram

Tags: javascript, instagram

i am developing an app to display images, from instagram, from different users and from one specified user i want to comment and like on the displayed images by making a cross origin request.

i have refered the links 
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/ and 
https://apigee.com/console/instagram

i have tried generating access token with scope="like+comments"

But every time i generate the access token i get "Only comments that you compose" permission on Comments and "Only with your express permission" on likes.

So i am able to like but when i try to comment i get response stating "error_message: "This client ID is not permitted to POST comments. For more info, please refer to our developer site at http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments."

How can i get a access token which will have express permissions and will let me comment on the pic.

Comment: This is v e r y  tedious. Write them a mail. Wait for half a year. Get down to ground with "They are not caring". That is it for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment permissions cant be obtained by simply using the clientID and access token.
You have to request this permission through mail.